# How to pass props as an argument to the variable in React

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project. In my project I have three components Home, Studentslist, Card.

My problem is passing data from Studentslist component to my Card component via props, right know I don't know why is not working.

I'm the reason why I'm passing that from Studentslist to Card is to reuse the Card component with different names.

If I was not clear enough with my question please leave a comment!

Below the code of my components:

This is Studentslist.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Studentslist.css';
import Card from '../../Components/Card/Card';

function Studentslist(props) {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div className='Departments'>
                        <button className='btn btn-primary'>Hockey</button>
                        <button onClick={() => setShow(true)} className='btn btn-primary ml-2'>Cricket</button>
                    </div>
                    <div className='table-responsive'>
                        <table className='table align-items-center table-flush'>
                            <thead className='thead-light'>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope='col'>No:</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Firstname</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Lastname</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Email</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Password</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Qualification</th>
                                    <th scope='col'>Branch</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    {show && <Card setShow={() => setShow(false)}
                        firstname={'Firstname'}
                        lastname={'Lastname'}
                    >
                    </Card>}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Studentslist
```

This is Card.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Card.css';

function Card({ setShow }, props) {
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row justify-content-center'>
                <div className='col-6'>
                    <div className='Registration'>
                        <form>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="firstname">{props.firstname}</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="firstname"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="lastname">{props.lastname}</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="lastname"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="email">{props.email}</label>
                                <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="password">{props.password}</label>
                                <input type="password" className="form-control" id="password"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="qualification">{props.qualification}</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="qualification"></input>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="branch">{props.branch}</label>
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="branch"></input>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            <button type="button" onClick={setShow} className='cancel btn btn-danger ml-2'>Cancel</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Card
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `Card` definition:

```js
function Card({ setShow }, props) {
    return (...)
}
```

It should be:

```js
function Card(props) {
    const { setShow } = props;
    return (...)
}
```

because `setShow` is included in the `props` of the `Card` component

Answer (score 0):

I think that `function Card({ setShow }, props)` will take setShow from props but your second argument 'props' will not be defined

You should make your function component declaration function `Card(props) {}` and then access the setShow as `props.setShow()`